How to tether on T-mobile Motorola Edge 2024 (Android 14)?
I bought a new Motorola Edge 2024, Android 14, and Kernel v5.10.198. The first thing I checked when I got home was tethering. I was shocked to see "not sharing internet" on the hotspot WiFi selector. Sure enough, upon configuration, a connected device could not ping Google.
It also says "sharing internet" on the Bluetooth selector. So I paired my Dell Inspiron 5502 laptop to my Android phone, and activated the Bluetooth tethering selector. My laptop is unable to ping over Bluetooth.
The only similar questions I found had to do with a Windows setting. I need the same for Ubuntu. I cannot find a way to enable Bluetooth IP networking on my Ubuntu 24.04 laptop.
Is there a way to bypass the WiFi tethering block on this new Android OS? If not, can anybody point me in the correct direction to configure my laptop correctly? I suspect that to be the issue.

You night need to explorer root options: https://github.com/evdenis/tether_unblock

@xavier_fakerat A computer reboot fixed it. I felt really foolish.
